# For Loop and displaying input values

Tags: python, loops, sorting, if-statement

Having trouble with the code returning the sorted values. As of now it returns as a T/F boolean statement, with all false values. I am trying to get the input to match the columns 'TDSP' and 'Class_charge' in the rates file. Any suggestions?

```
rates = pd.read_csv('x')

display(rates)


tdsp = input ("Enter tdsp :")

class_charge = input ("Enter class :")

for tdsp in rates:
    if (tdsp in rates):
        print(rates['TDSP'] == tdsp)
for class_charge in rates:
    if (class_charge in rates):
        print(rates['Class'] == class_charge)
```

Comment: You should be using `if tdsp in rates['TDSP']:`

Comment: First of all you're using the same variable name (e.g. tdsp, class_storage) so your initial input value will get override and also can you provide some example value on input and outputs.

Comment: rates ['TDSP'] contains 4 different parts: a,b,c,d

When I return a, nothing happens. and nothing is printed

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. I have read your question four times and I have absolutely no idea what you're trying to do. It doesn't help that you don't tell us what's in the csv file, nor what output you expect, nor what output you got.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it becomes a [mre]. In particular, it would be easier to reproduce your issue and help you if you replaced `rates = pd.read_csv('x')` with a hardcoded small dataframe such as `rates = pd.DataFrame({'TDSP': [12, 178, 54, 67], 'Class': ['light', 'heavy', 'medium', 'light'], ...})` and if you could replace `tdsp = input ("Enter tdsp :")` with `tdsp = some_explicit_hardcoded_value`.

Comment: rates = pd.read_csv('data')


CNP_TDSP= rates.loc[(rates['TDSP'] == 'CNP')]

TNMP_TDSP= rates.loc[(rates['TDSP'] == 'TNMP')]

AEPC_TDSP= rates.loc[(rates['TDSP'] == 'AEPC')]

AEPN_TDSP= rates.loc[(rates['TDSP'] == 'AEPN')]

ONC_TDSP= rates.loc[(rates['TDSP'] == 'ONC')]





userInput = str(input('Enter tdsp:'))




if userInput in rates['TDSP']:
    print(vars(userInput + '_TDSP'))
    



output: Enter tdsp: CNP      (which is what I entered)

Comment: Below are all the different TDSP variables, how would I get it to return the user-input TDSP variable based on the userInput. Sorry I am new to stackoverflow

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.